# pycurl module not available after installation on Snow Leopard

Tags: python, osx-snow-leopard, pycurl

I'm running Python 2.6.4 on Mac Snow Leopard. I installed pycurl using:

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" easy_install setuptools pycurl==7.16.2.1
```

The installation completes with no issues and says pycurl is installed in subsequent installation attempts. However, when I try to "import pycurl" in a script, I get a message that pycurl isn't found. I'm not sure what else to do to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suspect you have 2 versions of python on your system. How about removing easy install and reinstalling it.

Remove the current easy install script by typing `which easy_install` and then `rm [easy install full path]`.

To install easy install

```
wget http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py
python ez_setup.py
```

Then, try your command again:

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" easy_install setuptools pycurl==7.16.2.1
```

Comment: You were definitely on the right track. That *was* the problem. easy_install was from the native 2.4 version of Python that came with the OS. It was installing pycurl to that version. So I followed your steps and easy_install is definitely now running under 2.6.4. However, I now have a different problem.

Its trying to build using the 10.4 XCode SDK, which I don't believe I installed when I setup XCode. This is the error:

 from src/pycurl.c:35:
/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:108:14: warning: #warning Building for Intel with Mac OS X Deployment Target < 10.4 is invalid.

Comment: I think my next step is to try and install the older SDK and trying the build again.

Comment: I installed the 10.4 SDK on one computer to solve this problem and regretted it. I never put the 10.4 SDK on the current machine I'm working on, and just tested and the install worked for me using the easy_install command you gave.

Sorry I'm not of more help in diagnosing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have 2 different versions of python, you can find out by running command `which python`

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed Python 2.6.4 using the python.org OS X installer, you need to install the optional `10.4u SDK` from the 10.6 `Xcode` mpkg to install any python packages that include C extension modules.